# Why does the expression return a 0?

Tags: typescript, lambda, sum

I want to calculate a sum for a field in object.
The following works and returns a correct result if use filter `c.SectionId === sectionId` But function return 0 when calculating full sum for a field in object.
All values for field in objects are numbers. I'm sure of it. I think an error in expression but don't understand where.

```
calculateGroupTotal1(sectionId: number): number {
    if (sectionId === -1)
        this.model.Register10Data.map(c => c.Num1).reduce((sum, current) => (+sum) + (+current));
    return this.model.Register10Data.map(c => c.SectionId === sectionId ? c.Num1 : 0).reduce((sum, current) => (+sum) + (+current));
}
```

The `Register10Data` is an array that contains objects of the next type:

```
class Register10SectionViewModel {
        public Register10Id: number;
        public Id: number;
        public SectionId: number;
        public SectionTitle: string;    
        public AssetType: string;
        public CauseDisposal: string;
        public Num1: number;
        public Num2: number;
        public Num3: number;
        public Num4: number;
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

> I missed `return` in `this.model.Register10Data.map(c =>
>   c.Num1).reduce((sum, current) => (+sum) + (+current));`...

Comment: May we know what values you're putting in there…?

Comment: Hi. Look at fixed question.

Comment: Still have no idea what `this.model.Register10Data` contains…

Comment: Look at the question. Fixed again.